# Array: partial filling

Tags: c#, arrays

For a school assignment, I need to write a program where a user types two integers (which represents indexes) and then a method generates random numbers between those two numbers. For example: if a user types 3 and 8 and array length is 15 then a method will generate random numbers between index 3 and index 8 in an array. I'm trying something like this but it's not working:

```
        int[] arry = new int[15];

        int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Filling(a, b, arry);

        static void Filling(int a, int b, int[] arry)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = arry[a]; i < arry[b]; i++)
            {
                arry[i] = rnd.Next(3, 31);
                Console.WriteLine(arry[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `for (int i = arry[a]; i < arry[b]; i++)` -- you probably want `i` to loop from `a` to `b`, i.e. `for (int i = a; i < b; i++)`. Since `arry` starts off containg all zero's, `arry[a]` and `arry[b]` will both return `0`

Comment: Side note: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and believe me, it's worth every second spent in reading and understanding what one of the master mind behind Visual Studio has to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you want the loop to iterate between `a` and `b`. Not between the values stored in the array for a and b. i.e.

```
        for (int i = a; i < b; i++)
        {
            arry[i] = rnd.Next(3, 31);
            Console.WriteLine(arry[i]);
        }
```

You might also want to add some bounds-checking to ensure that a and b are valid. This can be done by clamping the index values before entering the loop.

```
        a = Math.Max(a, 0);
        b = Math.Min(b, arry.Count);
```